# How to make Qt creator automatically create kits for Android tool chains

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to configure Qt 5.11.2 (Qt creator 4.7.1) on a Windows 7 Pro machine to build applications for ARM Android v8. I think I've installed the Android SDK and NDK correctly, but Qt creator seems to be missing the tool chain for Android. I've read several other posts that suggest Qt Creator is able to automatically create the Android kits but that's not happening for me. Are there additional Android tool or component I need to install? Or are there additional Qt components missing?

Qt Creator Tools->Options->Devices->Android tab shows a yellow diamond with the message "Cannot create kits for all architectures. Qt versions missing for the following architectures: x86-linux-android-elf-64bit, arm-linux-android-elf-64bit"

Tools->Options->Devices->Android

[image]

Tools->Options->Kits

[image]

Tools->Options->Qt Versions

[image]

Tools->Options->Compilers

[image]

Comment: Qt recommends using NDK 10 IIRC, those new versions used to be problematic, maybe this is still the case. Newer NDK versions don't even have GCC as google switched to clang.

Comment: Thanks dtech that did it. After switching to NDK10 Qt automatically created the kit I needed to build for Android.